# Where to get country flag images for keyboard indicator

Tags: indicator, keyboard-layout

As it is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10223/display-current-layout-language-code-country-flag-in-keyboard-indicator/10268#10268) I wanted to show current country flag in a keyboard indicator. The problem is where to find those country flags.

Does anybody know where can I download country flags appropriate for keyboard indicator?

I have found one [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Faenza+and+Elementary?content=133726) but it only has language abbreviations, I need country flags instead.

Thank you.

Comment: You can find solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070231/show-flags-instead-of-labels-in-the-keyboard-layout-language-indicator-in-gnome?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three seconds of googling return a set of freely (as in beer) usable [flag icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/) - are these ok for your use case?

Comment: +1, probably the most well known/most used flag icons

Comment: Thanks for devoting your 3 seconds for me. I hope this question will help also others to solve their problems.