# How to display a flag instead of letters as language indicator in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: indicator, language-support

I tried some methods I found online but they don't work - maybe it's because of the Ubuntu version?

[image]

Instead of (En) for English, how can I have a US flag there instead?

Comment: Dunno if this still works: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22886/where-to-get-country-flag-images-for-keyboard-indicator

Comment: You can find solution in the link bellow: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070231/show-flags-instead-of-labels-in-the-keyboard-layout-language-indicator-in-gnome?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Go to: System Settings > Hardware > Input Devices > Keyboard > Layouts.

And then change it to *Show Flag* instead of *Show Label*.