# Show flags instead of labels in the keyboard layout language indicator in GNOME shell

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, indicator, gnome-shell, language-support

Is there a way to show flags instead of labels in the language indicator in the top panel, in gnome-shell (3.28)?

I found this setting in dconf-editor:
`/org/gnome/libgnomekbd/indicator/show-flags`
But it's ineffective, nothing changes if I set that to true.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a hacky workaround.

You need to change the abbreviations of layouts (e.g. "en") shown in the keyboard layout indicator of GNOME top bar following [this very detailed answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/944751/480481) by [@MathCubes](https://askubuntu.com/users/48372/mathcubes).
As mentioned in the answer the `<shortDescription>` tags in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` file dictate the abbreviations. Change the `<shortDescription>` labels associated to your chosen layouts (e.g. `en`) to suitable flag emojis (you can get them from [Get Emoji](https://getemoji.com/#flags) or [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/flags/)).

Since GNOME shell v3.28 supports [global colour emojis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022342/how-does-ubuntu-support-emojis), you should see coloured flags instead of labels after you reboot or re-login or restart the GNOME Shell.

> **Example:**
>   [image]
>   (after replacing `en` by  for the "English (UK)" layout)

Comment: This is AWESOME!
Thank you very much!
I wish I could make an extension for this.

Comment: Reboot is not required. It's enough to logout & login to take changes in effect.

Comment: @ks1322 Yes, even restarting the GNOME Shell is enough.

Answer (score 0):

✅ I made this extension exactly for that:
https://github.com/jasursadikov/gnome-language-flags
Thanks @pomsky for the reference.