# How to remove keyboard indicator?

Tags: unity, indicator

`/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/general/disable_indicator` in **gconf** is set to `yes`

Additionally I restarted, but it's still there.

Maybe there is some setting buried in CCSM?

---

here is screenshot of what I'm talking about if it's not clear:

[image]

I want to remove it if possible

Comment: What layouts show up if you click on the button? I don't remember but I think that button appeared for me *after* I added "USA Dvorak" to my list of Layouts [in gnome-keyboard-properties -> Layouts]

Comment: It does not show layout but drop-down menu for choosing layout: standard ASCII (USA) and my locale layout. Additionally there is menu shortcut for "keyboard preferences" and "show current layout".

Comment: Oh, so you have more than 1 keyboard layout or not?  If you have 2, try removing one [temporarily].  Then reboot, or log out and in again maybe?

Comment: Hm... I don't want to remove my locale layout. I just want to remove this icon, while still being able to switch layouts. I guess this (**gconf** option) was working for 10.10 at least, but it's not working now.

Comment: Alright then, guess I can't help ya..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

To completely remove the keyboard indicator we need to change one byte in the file

*11.04 and before*

`/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libkeyboard.so`

*11.10 and after*

`/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libkeyboard.so`

(make backup libkeyboard.so)

open file with root privileges through any hex editor (i use Bless)

and search for the byte signature `FF 83 F8 01 0F`

`FF 83 F8 01 0F` = if (g_slist_length (current_kbd_config.layouts_variants) > 1)

and change `01` to `02`

`FF 83 F8 02 0F`

save file

`FF 83 F8 02 0F` = if (g_slist_length (current_kbd_config.layouts_variants) > 2)

if you have less than 3 keyboard layouts icon will be not shown

after this work need to reload gnome-settings-daemon

you can use reboot for this.

Comment: Mine was at: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/

Answer (score 8):

In version 13.10 and newer of Ubuntu you can just tick it off in Text 'entry settings' (last menu options when you click the keyboard icon). Tick off the 'show current keyboard' option.

Answer (score 4):

If you find that the keyboard indicator is useless, you can easily remove the applet from top panel by following the steps below:

1. Open System Settings from Unity Launcher or from top-right corner shutdown menu. Then click on Text Entry
2. In the bottom of the window you’ll see “Show current input source in the menu bar” which is enabled by default. Uncheck the box and the indicator applet will disappear instantly.

Answer (score 3):

You can very simply do this in Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity desktop for the current user in the terminal by issuing the following command.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible false
```

If the user is not logged into a currently running Unity session, you can set the setting by running this.

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible false
```

Comment: Worked for me with 16.04

Answer (score 2):

If you wished to remove the Keyboard icon and keep the Language selector then it is as follows:

@ Terminal

1. find /usr/share/icons/ -name "input-keyboard.??g" -exec sudo mv {} {}.old \;
2. for i in $(find /usr/share/icons/ -name '*.old'); do sudo mv $i ${i%.*}; done

If you wished to remove both the Keyboard icon and the Language selector then it is as follows:

1. Open your Configuration Editor
2. Click Apps --> gnome_settings_daemon --> plugins --> Keyboard --> Unchecked 'Active'
3. Log out and log in. The Keyboard icon and the Language selector will not appear.

NB: If you couldn't locate your Keyboard at the Configuration Editor, then do this:
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=140209

Comment: I give you my bounty little too early. `Apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/Keyboard = 0` disables locale layout support, so that's not what I'm after.

Comment: "Flag" solution OTOH is best from provided answers, so I'll mark it as answered if there are no more answers in this couple of days. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Keyboard Indicators plugins" may have been installed. Run the Software Center to check and remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately "Keyboard Indicators plugins" is not installed. This indicator applet appeared right after I installed (and updated) 11.04, some days ago

Comment: Check out the dconf-editor under org - gnome - libgnomekbd - indicator. There are some parameters there that may be helpful, namely enabled-plugins and perhaps show-flags. It the only other thing I could think of although I have to admit being in guess mode because I can't duplicate you situation.

Comment: There is no such key in dconf-editor. Additionally I browsed for any trace of this indicator without success