# Is it possible to hide arbitrary panel indicators?

Tags: indicator, panel, indicator-message

Is there a way to hide arbitrary indicators (like messages, keyboard layout)?

I don't have enough screen resolution to have 10+ indicators, so I want to remove some that I don't feel are necessary.

Comment: They are not that arbitrary (they are part of the accessibility). Can you add to your question why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the messages panel you could just remove it. I did that too and it works fine:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages
```

I don't know how to hide the keyboard layout panel, but as far as I know if you remove all but one kayboard layout it will be automatically hidden.

Edit: So here is how to hide the keyboard layout panel: [How to remove keyboard indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69720/how-to-remove-keyboard-indicator)

Comment: I need more than 1 keyboard layout :P That's why I have more than one keyboard layout.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69720/how-to-remove-keyboard-indicator

Comment: Add the hex editing to your answer so I can give you credit.