# Removing keyboard indicator on Top panel in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I would like to know how to disable/remove the keyboard/language indication from the gnome top panel in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to remove all input sources but the one you use?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson not sure how to do that, I believe English (UK) and English (US) are both and the only two options and I really don't need English (US) to be there as I will only ever be using English(UK) and the UK keyboard layout. 

So how would I be able to go ahead and remove the option of English (US) ? and i presume this will ensure the icon goes away as there are no longer multiple input options?

Thanks

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.18/keyboard-layouts.html

Answer (score 4):

On **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**, with **gnome-flashback**, the keyboard applet look like this:

[image: keyboard indicator screenshot]

This icon in applet indicator cannot be easily removed as it used to be (a tick in the keyboard preference was available in the previous Ubuntu version)

But this command does the trick:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible false
```

(source: https://askubuntu.com/a/629072/681889)

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Got `No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.keyboard”` on Ubuntu 20.04…

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by removing other input sources than Chinese.

gnome-control-center -> region and language -> input source, delete others except zh-hans, then the indicator disappears right away.

Comment: The answer is about hiding the icon, not removing other input sources. One can use two keyboard layouts at the same time and want to remove the icon.