# Where is directory for keyboard indicator flag picture in GNOME 3?

Tags: keyboard, indicator, gnome, directory

For unity environment, I know it is /usr/share/pixmaps/flags + change setting org.gnome.libgnomekbd.indicator to true, which is totally successful.

But for Gnome-shell ,both default and classic, system cannot finds the flags and displays the "picture not found" picture instead.

So where is the Gnome-shell directory for keyboard indicator flag ? Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy flags picture into `/usr/share/pixmaps/flags` and name it - `us-symbolic.png`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the indicator used, usually it is in `~/.icons` or `~/.icons/flags`.
Take a detailed look also in this question:

> [Display current layout (language code/country flag) in keyboard indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10223/display-current-layout-language-code-country-flag-in-keyboard-indicator/207260#207260)