# Keyboard Indicator shows red X

Tags: indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display current layout (language code/country flag) in keyboard indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10223/display-current-layout-language-code-country-flag-in-keyboard-indicator)

Before upgrade to 12.10, I had ~/.icons/flags shown. After the upgrade, even if the folder exists and dconf is set to use flags instead of text, the flags don't show. The problem is that I cannot change to text to show the languages.

Even though on logon the language EN is shown, when I log to unity the red X comes to its place.

Please help, It's a rather frustrating situation...

Comment: The same problem. I had ~/.icons/flags/ and after upgrade to 12.10 I have red sign. And I don't know how to restore keyboard icon + language code.

Comment: I found a working solution in [Display current layout (language code/country flag) in keyboard indicator](http://askubuntu.com/a/207260/49686).