# Is there a keyboard switcher for Ubuntu that displays a country flag instead of two-letter code?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Is there a way to make keyboard indicator in Ubuntu display country flags instead of two-letter codes? This feature of [SwitchIt!](http://www.switchit.ru/) layout switcher for Windows is the only one I miss in Ubuntu.

[image: SwitchIt! keyboard layout switcher for Windows]

Or, maybe there is a way to display overlay on a screen briefly, when the layout is switched? Like this one in Apple products:

[image: Apple overlay]

**Added**: I have Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Duplicate Question --- http://askubuntu.com/questions/10223/display-current-layout-language-code-country-flag-in-keyboard-indicator

Comment: @Tasos Yes, it's kind of a duplicate. However, it was not updated for a while. How could I ask someone to provide a solution that works for more recent versions of Ubuntu? Also, I didn't mention it, but I would prefer a command-line solution if possible. Maybe there's a ready package or script for that?

Comment: Your correct, the flags seem to have been removed in 13.10. I will check and get back to you if i find anything. Can you amend your question to mention what version of Ubuntu you have.

Comment: @Tasos 13.10. Added. I thought there's a solution (like a program in ppa) that should work for several Ubuntu versions, so that's why I didn't specify version.

Comment: Well so far i cant find a utility out there for keyboard flags for 13.10 +. I'm surprised no one has has done one yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display current layout (language code/country flag) in keyboard indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10223/display-current-layout-language-code-country-flag-in-keyboard-indicator)