# displaying country flags in the keyboard indicator

Tags: unity

Is it possible to display country flags in the keyboard layout indicator on Ubuntu 17.04 with Unity?

Comment: Try proberties on the keyboard layout indicator.
Change the layout from tekst to image!
This works on most of the other windows managers - so see if it works on Unity too!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display current layout (language code/country flag) in keyboard indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10223/display-current-layout-language-code-country-flag-in-keyboard-indicator)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for the current versions of Ubuntu and Unity, it took me some time to figure out.

Install gxkb: an application which adds a flag indicator to the top panel:

```
sudo apt-get install gxkb
```

Run the installed program, it should display the current language indicator at the top panel. The "&" at the end ensures that the program will not exit upon closing the terminal:

```
gxkb &
```

Then, hide the old indicator like this: go to
`System settings -> Text Entry` and  untick `Show current input source in the menu bar`.

To ensure that gxkb launches at the startup, run the following:

```
 gnome-session-properties
```

Click on `Add`.
In the field `Name:`, type any name and in the field `Command:`, type `gxkb`.

You can override the default flags with your custom flags, they should be of the size 24 x 24 px in png format, you can download some nice flags here:
https://www.whoishostingthis.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Flags-Icon-Set.zip.
Place the custom flags which you want to use into `~/.local/share/gxkb/flags/`.
Name each flag as `<country code>.png`, e.g. `us.png`, `ru.png`.