# How to show current keyboard layout on mate-panel as country flag?

Tags: keyboard-layout, mate

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.

I want to change current keyboard layout indication from text (for example `ru`, `en`) to the corresponding country flags.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and newer you need to send one command:

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator show-flags true
```

it will change MATE Panel appearance from

[image: ru in mate-panel]

to

[image: russian flag in mate-panel]

---

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS having MATE 1.12 this method does not work out-the-box (it is [bug 1783543](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libmatekbd/+bug/1783543)), but we have two options here:

- download flags manually and place them in home folder:

  ```
    mkdir -p ~/.icons/flags
    cd ~/.icons/flags/
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linuxmint/flags/master/usr/share/iso-flag-png/{ru,us}.png
  ```

  then toggle layout indicator state:

  ```
    gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator show-flags false
    gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator show-flags true
  ```

  and we will get flags in place. Note: I used `ru` and `us`, you can pick others from [LinuxMint GitHub repository](https://github.com/linuxmint/flags/tree/master/usr/share/iso-flag-png).
- use newer MATE 1.16 from official [xenial-mate PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/xenial-mate):

  ```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/xenial-mate
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```

  then enable flags

  ```
    gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator show-flags true
  ```

  and we can get flags in place after reboot and login.

---

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS we need to download flags manually (as in 16.04 LTS):

```
mkdir -p ~/.icons/flags
cd ~/.icons/flags/
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linuxmint/flags/master/usr/share/iso-flag-png/{ru,us}.png
```

then toggle layout indicator state:

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator show-flags false
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator show-flags true
```

and we will get flags in place.

Comment: can we do the same thing with a standard Ubuntu (using `gnome`)? NB: you lost connection after appearance change

Comment: The solution above does not fail on theme appearance change. It may fail if somebody miss flag for new language :) About GNOME currently we have solution for Unity (runs `indicator-keyboard`) and GNOME FlashBack (using `gnome-panel` with `indicator-keyboard`) on [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/1059434/66509).